# how to make my custom attribute an attribute of configuration m2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, configuration

I want to create a configurable product according to my custom attribute but i can't find it when i pass create configurations here is my code

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,'choix_prix_product');
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'choix_prix_product',/* Custom Attribute Code */
        [
            'type' => 'text',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Choix-Prix de vente', /* lablel of your attribute*/
            'input' => 'select',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '', /* Source of your select type custom attribute options*/
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => true,
            'is_configurable'=>1,
            'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => false,
            'unique' => false,

            'is_visible_in_grid' => false


        ]

    );
}
```

and here is my observer to stock options dynamically according to custom table data also i faced problem here instead of finding the  just values of this product i found all the value of existing product how to manage this here is my code

```
class Editoptions implements ObserverInterface
```

{
    protected $_logger;

```
protected $_attributeRepository;

protected $_attributeOptionManagement;

protected $_option;

protected $_attributeOptionLabel;


public function __construct( \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
                             \Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository $attributeRepository,
                             \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface $attributeOptionManagement,
                             \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionLabelInterface $attributeOptionLabel,
                             \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Option $option

) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->_attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    $this->_attributeOptionManagement = $attributeOptionManagement;
    $this->_option = $option;
    $this->_attributeOptionLabel = $attributeOptionLabel;
}


public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object

   // $att=$this->createOrGetId('choix_prix_product', $label); for adding new option to our attribute

    $_sku = $_product->getSku(); // for sku

    $var1 = substr($_sku, 0, 1);


    $var2 = substr($_sku, 1, 2);

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('table_prix');


    $fields = array('prix_unitaire','prix_id');


    $sql = $connection->select()
        ->from($tableName, $fields)
        ->where('code_famille' . '=?', $var1)
        ->where('code_nom_commercial' . '=?', $var2)
        ->join('table_choix',
            'table_choix.choix_id = table_prix.code_choix',
            [
                'designation_choix'
            ]);

    $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

    $attribute_id = $this->_attributeRepository->get('catalog_product', 'choix_prix_product')->getAttributeId();






    if ($result) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($result as $elt) {
            /* new attribute option */

            $this->_option->setValue(" Choix" . $elt['designation_choix'] . "-" . $elt['prix_unitaire'] . "£");

            $this->_attributeOptionLabel->setStoreId(0);
            $this->_attributeOptionLabel->setLabel(" Choix" . $elt['designation_choix'] . "-" . $elt['prix_unitaire'] . "£");
            $this->_option->setLabel($this->_attributeOptionLabel);
            $this->_option->setStoreLabels([$this->_attributeOptionLabel]);

            $this->_attributeOptionManagement->add('catalog_product', $attribute_id, $this->_option);


            $i++;

        }




    } /*else {

        $this->_options = [['label' => __(' '), 'value' => '0']];
        $_product->setData('choix_prix_product', $this->_options);

    }*/


}
```

any help please